# How do I get around the IE CSS percentage rounding problem?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, width, css-float

I'm trying to create a dynamic site where I have three floating boxes next to eachother. They are 33.33% in width each. The container div around them is 75% in width.

I've found an article about the problem here: [CSS: Jumping columns](http://www.ojctech.com/content/css-jumping-columns-and-ies-percentage-rounding-algorithm)
I've also found an example of the same problem here: [Jumping columns example](http://emma.ojctech.com/~rohde/public/CSS-quirks/percentage-rounding/JumpingColumns.html)

Drag the window size to see the jumping in IE7 or earlier.

Anyone knows if it's possible to get around this? (without Javascript)

Answer (score 14):

I use two different solutions depending on the situation. First, try the Nicole Sullivan approach (using `overflow: hidden;` on the final element in a row instead of float/width):

http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/

```
.container {
  width: 75%;
}

.box1 {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  display: inline; /* fixes another IE bug */
}

.box2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This works in most cases.

Failing that, I add a negative margin of several pixels to the last element instead.

```
.box2 {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  display: inline; /* fixes another IE bug */
  margin-right: -3px;
}
```

If that last element is floated right instead, just add the negative margin to the left. So far that has worked for me in the few cases where `overflow` didn't fit.

Comment: This secret benefit of the overflow property is *sexy*

Answer (score 2):

In a situation like this, I would tend to get round the problem using an IE-only stylesheet that fudges the values until they work. In this case, just set the widths to 33%, it won't be perfect but then that's just the nature of the web.

Comment: Thanks Rory. I know it could be solved that way and I might be forced to do that in case noone else have a better idea. It's a kind of an ugly way to solve it.

Comment: It's also a necessity in many cases unfortunately. The least ugly/hackish way to go about it would be conditional comments.

Comment: "It's a kind of an ugly way to solve it" yes and no, okay you could call it a hack but I'd be very surprised if anyone can come up with something neater, most IE6 hacks are far worse!

Comment: I don't mind the hack. 33.33% gives the jumping in IE and if I change that to for example 33% to prevent the jumping, the widths are too small at some sizes. 33% is a wrong number, and then the widths get wrong. That's what bugging me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a simple answer might be to not round at all, just create a final "spacer" element with a 1% width that shares the look of the 1/3rd elements.  Even IE should be able to deal with a 33 + 33 + 33 + 1 rounding.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. ie7 did not render 33.33% correctly. It would work with 33% but then it was a hairline off. I used the advice from the second block of code in the first response above, plus a little ie hack. It worked for me, I hope it helps.

```
.all-boxes {
   width: 33.33%;
   float: left;
   display: inline;
   *margin-right: -1px; /* Add the asterisk */
 }
```

The margin value might need to change based on your implementation, but 1px worked for me.