# does IE8 supports width values as percentages?

Tags: forms, internet-explorer-8, width, percentage, pixel

does IE8 supports width values set as percentages? I have a form which width value is set to 33.33% but IE8 ignores that value, unless is set in pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, IE has a problem when rounding numbers. This article here discusses your exact problem, check it out: http://www.pixotech.com/css-jumping-columns-ies-percentage-rounding-algorithm/

For possible solutions, check this post here: [How do I get around the IE CSS percentage rounding problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084469/how-do-i-get-around-the-ie-css-percentage-rounding-problem)